# How much more energy does it take for a human body to heat 0C ice vs 0C water?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat

I'm trying to determine if going through the trouble of ingesting ice is worth the hassle versus ingesting ice-cold *water*, but my physics skills are rusty.

If I drink a gram of ice *water* at ~0C, my body has to heat the water to 37C.

[Per wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity#Table_of_specific_heat_capacities), the water will be heated by

$$1\text{ g} \times \underbrace{37\text{ K}}_\text{Temperature difference} \times \underbrace{ 4.1813 \frac{\text{J}}{\text{g K}}}_\text{Specific heat of water} = 155\text{ J}$$

Whereas if I ingest a gram of *ice*, in addition to those 155 Joules, it will need to heat by [334 Joules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_heat#Specific_latent_heat) to do the transformation from ice to liquid.  So the payoff to ingesting *ice* instead of water is about 3 times more calories burned.

Is my reasoning sound?

*Note: You could turn my question into a meta-question by attacking the logic of ingesting cold water for burning calories, but please be so kind as to keep your answers to the physics question I've stated.*

Comment: Hi Ross, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is actually not a bad physics question at all. Since it's a physics site, we're not going to care about the logic of drinking cold water to burn calories - that's part of the weird world of biology ;-) In fact if you had asked whether drinking cold water burns calories we'd probably come up with a model just like what you have here.

Comment: You'd have to ingest 1.7kg of ice to burn off the energy of one average donut.

Comment: Which is better than $$ 1.7 \times 3.15 = 5.35 kg $$ of 0C water :-)  It also explains why I'm not in the TGIF donut club.  It may be quackery, but thanks for the physics analysis. :-)

Comment: It'd be interesting to see how eating ice compares to not wearing a sweater on a cold day in terms of calories burned.

Comment: I believe part of the biological response is hormonal and unrelated  to the specific energy transfer, so the actual thermic shock is important to seeing a hormonal response. See [\[1\]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1550413111000131) and [\[2\]](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0014299902014309).  Anyways, giving it the old college try to see what happens.  Pro'lly  wont kill me.

Comment: @Nick Does chocolate ice also count?

Comment: Showering in liquid nitrogen won't make you lose weight...in the classic sense, at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your reasoning is sound.

However, being in Melbourne, Australia (which is heading for 35 C today), I can think of better applications of eating ice than burning calories.  You would certainly experience a greater drop in body temperature by consuming equal amounts of ice versus water at 0 C.

Answer (score -3):

I think $334$ joules is not right, you should calculate the energy of a gram of ice to melt/become water at 0C than add energy that you have calculated above. Please find the latent energy of melting. If you calculate correctly, you need much bigger energy to swallow a gr of ice until it becomes water at $37^o \text{C}$ in your body.

Comment: That is, in fact, what he has done.  That's why he says "3 times more calories burned" instead of 2 times.